# display mysql data in PHP with explode

Tags: php, mysql, explode

[image]

I want to display only the specific user details as shown in link. For kind information, I just want to say that I am using php and mysql and need to display 'user2' details from that previous table(customer) given as picture link].help with valuable suggestion.

Comment: if I use sql- SELECT id,rcvusr FROM xyz WHERE rcvusr='user2'  ORDER BY eid desc LIMIT 10. it display only 2 records(id 13 and 14)

Comment: Hello, _Jaywalker anti-pattern_! //Hint: do not store multiple values in one column

Comment: try sql like -- SELECT id,rcvusr FROM xyz WHERE rcvusr like '%user2%' ORDER BY eid desc LIMIT 10

Comment: Dear Aneesh, Thanks. It's good, atleast i can make it on my way. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT id,rcvusr FROM xyz WHERE rcvusr like 'user2%' ORDER BY eid desc LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id, sndusr, SUBSTRING_INDEX(rcvusr, '@@', 1), title
From xyz
Where rcvusr = 'user2' or
    rcvusr like 'user2@@%'
```

Here is the documentation :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index